# Проблема в ссылках админки Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url

Добрый день, сообщество.

Столкнулся с проблемой, решения которой ищу второй день. И буду рад любым полезным советам по данному вопросу. А дело вот в чем:

Есть сайт на Wordpress. И главная его страница находится по адресу www.domain.ru/blog/ . Я знаю, что это не самоелучшее решение - размещать главную страницу по адресу в таком виде, но это 1) сайт не мой и 2)блог хранится на отдельном сайта www.domain.ru хостинге.

Все записи этого блога доступны по ссылкам вида www.domain.ru/blog/post-name/

Но странное начинатся при входе в админку.

Кнопка админки на ссылается на адрес www.domain.ru/blog/wp-admin/
При нажатии на кнопку я попадаю на главную страницу админки. И в адресной строке браузера сначала появляется адрес www.domain.ru/blog/wp-admin/ и быстро меняется на www.domain.ru/wp-admin/ . То есть слово /blog в URL пропадает.

И это приводит к тому, что остальные ссылки на панели администрирования тоже приобретают вид www.domain.ru/wp-admin/settings-page/ , при переходе на которые возникает ошибка 404.

Я проверил, что если попытаться зайтипо ссылке вида www.domain.ru/blog/wp-admin/settings-page/, то все происходит корректно.

В связи с отсутствием идей решения проблемы, обращаюсь к Вам за советом. 
Конечная цель - заставить админку работать правильно и генерировать на панели администрирования ссылки вида www.domain.ru/blog/wp-admin/settings-page/ на кнопках и формах.

UPD: содержимое .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType 'text/html; charset=utf-8' .html .htm .shtml
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Искали в таблицах БД строку "www.domain.ru"? Возможно, где-то в `wp_options` хранится неправильный url сайта

Comment: @alenkins Да, искал. И делал grep по некоторым каталогам. Не нашлось ничего противоречащего

Comment: ну и в `wp-config.php` ещё можно посмотреть на то, что задано для `WP_HOME` и `WP_SITEURL`

Comment: @alenkins Просмотрел все конфиги. Все указанные параметры установлены в www.domain.ru/blog/

Comment: Можно посмотреть во внутренности `.htaccess`. Вообще, вы бы перечислили то, что уже проверяли, чтобы понимать, что уже было проверено

Comment: @alenkins В общем, мне нечего добавить о проверенных файлах. Я проверял как раз основные конфиги и БД. С htaccess тоже пробовал ковыряться, но желаемого результата это не принесло. Добавил содержиоме .htaccess

Comment: у меня довольно много вордпресс сайтов в каталогах одного домена. Содержимое `.htaccess` примерно следующее http://screencast.com/t/LX5jx0ASf обратите внимание на `RewriteBase` и `RewriteRule`

Comment: @alenkins Да, такого вида конфиг я тоже пытался писать. Но с ним у меня при попытке открыть пост возникала ошибка Internal Server Error с белым экраном. В логах информация об этой ошибке не отображалась.

Comment: насколько я знаю, правка руками этого файла в случае с вордпрессом почти всегда заканчивается неудачей. а пробовали удалить его и пересохранить настройки постоянных ссылок в админке wp (изменить пару раз)? вордпресс должен будет создать `.htaccess` по-новой, с учётом всех актуальных настроек url. только сделайте копию рабочего `.htaccess` обязательно

Comment: @alenkins описанная мною в заголовке поста ситуация произошла после обновления вордпресса. И там был новый сгенерированный .htaccess . Но изменить настройки пермалинков не представляется возможным в силу того, что форма на странице настроек посылает данные формы по нажатию кнопки Submit на неверный URL. Единственный выход - разобрать POST-запрос и послать его руками. Но сгенерированный файл в итоге получается именно таким, каким я его Вам показываю.

Answer (score 1):

На совсем крайний случай, если не найдёте причину, то попробуйте обойти ошибку, например, добавив фильтр на `login_redirect` и `logout_redirect`:

```
function login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user){
    return home_url('/wp-admin/'); /* или задайте адрес совсем константой, если home_url() возвращает неправильный url */
    die();
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3);
add_filter('logout_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3);
```